# Does CiviCRM work with Drupal 8 and how can I help?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

What is the status of CiviCRM working with Drupal 8? And how can I help in terms of testing or funding this development?

Comment: The previous answers are now almost a year old. Where can I find a more recent status update?

Comment: See related question about Drupal 9: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/what-is-the-status-of-civicrm-working-with-drupal-9

Answer (score 20):

UPDATE: Please head to this [Q+A](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/where-is-the-documentation-for-installing-civicrm-with-drupal-8-or-for-upgrading/36248#36248) for documentation information / links or head direct to the [installation documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/)

There is a channel on Chat [here](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/drupal)

Comment: Thanks for this Pete. Do you know if D8/Civi can be spun up with buildkit?

Comment: Eileen's done some work on that, not sure if it's ready yet or not

Comment: Yes we totally understand the need to get D8 and civi firing up on BuildKit and having been putting some time in to this but not fully completed. Current focus (and funding) is on ensuring CiviCRM works with beta14

Comment: Note the first link about the code for the drupal module part is now https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 as of May, 2018, instead of https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/tree/8.x-master.

Comment: Thanks for the edit/update Demerit

Comment: The "Make It Happen" page gives "access denied", so it has been put offline I think. It is not clear to me why. Did it reach its goal, what will happen further, when will the Drupal 8 version will be released, why is there no blog post or any news why the page has been put offline?

Comment: V good question - will update my Answer and I may add a new question about documentation specifically

Comment: I think JIRA is ancient history - and be removed?

Answer (score 14):

Active Development has restarted on the Drupal 8 version. It is possible to get it installed now, although it takes a slight different process than with Drupal 7.

Assuming you have Drupal 8.2.5 installed.

Download and install the 8.x-3.x-dev version of the Libraries module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries

Download the most recent version of CiviCRM 4.7 from CiviCRM.org , or if your a little more adventurous, the [master branch from github](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/).

Put CiviCRM core in /libraries folder of your Drupal 8 installation.

Delete the Drupal 7 modules from this download which would now be in /libraries/civicrm/drupal . You can delete the whole drupal folder.

Next get the 8.x-master branch of the [CiviCRM Core drupal module](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/tree/8.x-master)

Put this in your standard Drupal 8 modules directory, /modules/civicrm

Now log in to your Drupal 8 site and goto /admin/modules

Enable CiviCRM, but do it by itself, do not enable any other modules at the same time.

This will attempt to install CiviCRM in the same database as your Drupal installation.

You will get some feedback if it has issues connecting to the database. 
If you get a "cannot connect to database" message, try the one line temporary fix documented in this issue:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19835
There will be a fix soon for this issue

Now you will have CiviCRM installed. In my experience, there was an error at the root civicrm page at path /civicrm , due to something with the Dashboard.  To fix this you must simply set the default organization and email address and From Name here: civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1

After that, all the CiviCRM pages will load, you will see the CiviCRM menu.

There are some issues that are being worked out, but at this point CiviCRM is usable.  We need people testing this and documenting issues so that they can be resolved.

Comment: Great to hear! Congrats to all involved.

Answer (score 9):

See answer from @jackrabbithanna for current status.

tl;dr : It's not yet production ready, and the list of things you can help on is in JIRA at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17652?filter=23012 . Additionally, please create additional issues and mark Label them drupal-8.

Building on the previous work, Allen Shaw made some progress recently with assistance from Tim, Coleman and Nicolas at the Vail Colorado sprint hosted by Nicolas Ganivet.

The navigation menu and dashboard are now working.

For convenient assistance with developing, it is now possible to install D8 with CiviCRM using

civibuild create d8-master

Also, the new cividev environment builder ( https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit-vagrant/blob/master/README.md) can
configure a VirtualBox using Vagrant on your local machine with this or other builds supported by buildkit.

However, various issues need to be resolved before CiviCRM can be run in production with D8 as of mid-February 2016.

Comment: Is there a list of issues that remain that can be linked to?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17652?jql=labels%20%3D%20drupal8%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%2C%20%22In%20Quality%20Assurance%22%2C%20%22In%20Verification%22)

Comment: Thanks, Pete. I created a JIRA filter and added link to the search results in the post.

Answer (score 6):

You could also try the RoundEarth distribution: https://gitlab.com/mydropwizard/roundearth-drops-8

> "RoundEarth is a template for building a website for a nonprofit
>   organization, based on Drupal 8 and CiviCRM."

Comment: This is the best way to do it now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the current easiest and best way is to:

1. Install Drupal 8 with the [recommended composer template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies)

   composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_site_name_dir
2. Add CiviCRM:

   cd my_site_name_dir
   composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:^5.25 civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:^5.25 civicrm/civicrm-packages:^5.25
3. Enable CiviCRM in the modules list

Comment: Yes there's some official documentation coming. Note that step 2 as written will install a development version - most people probably want to restrict it to a particular numbered version, e.g. `composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:^5.25 civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:^5.25 civicrm/civicrm-packages:^5.25`. Also make sure in step 2 that you run that from within my_site_name_dir, i.e. first `cd my_site_name_dir`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer

Comment: Documentation is now available: https://docs.civitest.me/installation/en/latest/drupal8/

Comment: Thanks @hans-rossel just that was Mikey's preview site. The real one is at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/

Comment: aha, I was wondering what the test domainname was, found the url in https://civicrm.org/blog/karing/drupal-8-webform-civicrm-beta1 so maybe should be updated there too.

Comment: Good point. I'll mention it in chat.

Comment: Fixed in my blog post! Thanks Hans and Demerit