# Drupal 8.0.1 compatibility with CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, compatiblity

Is the newest version of CiviCRM compatible with the newest 8.0.1 version of drupal? I have loaded drupal on my VPS but wonder if I load CiviCRM into the module folder, if it will be reccognized. If I have to delete 8.0.1 and reload drupal 7 please advise. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid CiviCRM doesn't support Drupal 8 yet.  You will need to install Drupal 7.

You can find more details here: [Installation and Upgrades](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades)

See also this question: [Does CiviCRM work with Drupal 8 and how can I help?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/does-civicrm-work-with-drupal-8-and-how-can-i-help)