# Drupal 8 - what's the status?

Tags: drupal-8

What is the status of the Drupal 8 integration?

1. Does anyone know of anyone using, or gearing up to using, a Drupal 8 & Civi production install?
2. Does anyone know how much (if any) core team time is being focused on Drupal 8 integration?
3. Is there a dedicated anywhere (forum, mailing list, twitter hashtag?!) for Drupal 8 integration updates?

John

PS: I am aware of the Jira issues queue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18222?filter=23012

Comment: I presume you've seen this related question http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/does-civicrm-work-with-drupal-8-and-how-can-i-help?rq=1

Comment: Yes - but it's half a year ago. Coders move fast, especially in the Civiverse!

Comment: Yes, it would be good to have an update!

Comment: if it makes more sense to keep the other SE question updated am happy to do so. Fuzion haven't been involved with this since the Feb sprint. Our interest definitely waned when it seemed more likely that Webform wouldn't be part of D8