# What's the optimal way to install and track CiviCRM with Drupal and git?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-buildkit, drush, drupal-8, deployment

First, I know compatibility with Drupal 8 is [not full yet](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/). There are still open bugs, a bunch of open PRs and an apparent lack of code review.

But let's ignore that for a moment and consider civi d8-ready. I want to do a test install for a migration from Joomla, but also maintain some level of tracking, so it's easier to work with custom changes and any (*knock on wood*) malicious ones are easier to detect and revert. Looking at various docs, I've found at least these options:

- classical install: drupal, civi
- drush: nicely handles downloads, upgrades and backups (no idea if it has VCS support by itself)
- composer: seems to be unofficially preferred for drupal8; not that much info available; more dependency heavy
- civi-buildkit: seems like a complete overkill, as I don't need a full development environment

All of them can be preceded by initing a blank git repo and manually tracking from there. The buildkit is already fully based on git. **Can any of** the others track upstream automatically, to avoid the need for manual commits-on-update and working with tarballs? Did I forget an even better option, some combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush can support VCS deployments and you can tell drush make to keep the .git directory with "drush make --working-copy your-platform.make". However, unless it's changed recently, drush doesn't have post-install hooks, so it won't handle composer/bower/npm well.

Composer has support for "post-install-cmd", but civicrm itself is not on packagist. I'm not familiar enough with composer to comment further, but from experiences so far, I find Composer more interesting than Drush on many many aspects (not CMS-specific, huge community, great tool).

Personally, and this is not an ideal solution: I build platforms (drupal+contrib+civicrm+extensions) using the tar.gz of each project. Extensions/themes that are actively developed get added as git submodules. All my servers use the same git repo (except for site-specific extensions/themes/modules which are in their own repos) and when I do upgrades, I run a git pull everywhere.

The main down side to this is that I cannot cherry-pick patches from upstream, which was the main issue of your question. I usually apply patches manually.

The main issue I had with running upstream git in production, is that this means I have to run composer/bower/npm/gencode on all production servers whenever there is a new version. That has a too high risk of failing (I manage ~ 20 servers, some with a mix of 4.7-D6, 4.7-D7, 4.6-D7, 4.7-WP).