# What is the difference between civicrm-drupal/tree/8.x-master and civicrm-drupal-8?

Tags: drupal-8

In [Does CiviCRM work with Drupal 8 and how can I help?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/does-civicrm-work-with-drupal-8-and-how-can-i-help/4416#4416) it mentions https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/tree/8.x-master, but from all the other instructions and as best as I can tell https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8 is the correct one to use. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The history of the branches started to diverge around Apr, 2018, and there's a comment on May 1 about creating a separate repo (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/523#issuecomment-385612657):

> To facilitate distribution via composer, the Civi-D8 code is being migrated to a new repository with a slightly different branch naming convention (ie civicrm-drupal@8.x-master becomes civicrm-drupal-8@master).

So at the moment for drupal 8 the more current code to use for the drupal module part is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8.