# What is the status of CiviCRM working with Drupal 9?

Tags: drupal

With the official release only a few days away (June 3, 2020) and the Drupal 9 porting weekend having just completed with a big effort by KarinG (https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/314), what is the status of CiviCRM working with Drupal 9?

Comment: See also related question about Drupal 8: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/does-civicrm-work-with-drupal-8-and-how-can-i-help

Answer (score 3):

Trying to upgrade a D8.8.6 site to D9 ->

```
karins-MBP:d9civicrm.local sysadmin$ composer require drupal/core-recommended:~9.0.0@dev drupal/core-composer-scaffold:~9.0.0@dev --update-with-dependencies --no-update
./composer.json has been updated
karins-MBP:d9civicrm.local sysadmin$ composer update
```

Found two issues:

```
symfony conflict -> Drupal 9 requires 4.4
civicrm/civicrm-core 5.25.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.8.50 || ~3.0

pear exception conflict: Can only install one of: pear/pear_exception[v1.0.1, v1.0.0]; - pear/log 1.13.1 requires pear/pear_exception 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by pear/pear_exception[v1.0.0].
```

WIP PR by Core Team -> to resolve the symfony conlict: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17380

And resolved!

This now works:

a) create a D8 project ->

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project d9civicrm.local
```

b) `cd d9civicrm.local`

c) `composer require civicrm/civicrm-core:dev-master civicrm/civicrm-packages:dev-master civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:dev-master civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:~1.0.1`

Go through the usual motions of installing D8 in your favourite language, database and timezone -> and then enable CiviCRM Core [you will need to ensure your `web/sites/default dir` is writable for the `civicrm.settings.php` file to be generated].

d) then onto D9 ->

```
composer require pear/pear_exception:'1.0.1 as 1.0.0'
```

e) `rm composer.lock`

f) `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9.0 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.0 drupal/core-project-message:^9.0 drupal/core-dev:^9.0 --update-with-all-dependencies`

And that produces:
[image]

Next step is here: `https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/pull/40/files`
[that will make CiviCRM installable as a D9 module].

Many more steps to go I'm sure! Thanks to Core Team and Mikey for their quick action on some of these items!

Update -> as of June 03 - 2020 -> webform_civicrm module is officially D9 Compatible:

[image]

Comment: latest from Chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/d71dtacth7n97buncexo8jc8dr

Comment: I'm sure there will be bumps ahead [possible breaking changes in webform module itself] - but we're close to where we can be at this point.

Comment: do you want to update the answer with what you had pasted in CHat?

Comment: Ok done - also included the most recent acquia report - clean slate now!

Comment: In step a) the title should be " create a D9 project or latest Drupal" because that composer command will install whatever the latest version is at the time

Answer (score 3):

As of CiviCRM version 5.31, Civi will work with Drupal 9.  https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/civicrm-531-release