# Where is the documentation for installing CiviCRM with Drupal 8 or for upgrading a Drupal 7 system with Civi to Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, documentation

This question is being asked so that it becomes the go to Answer for documentation / installation / migration questions hopefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the primary location for documentation is

- [Installation](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/)
- Migration of a CiviCRM system from D7 to D8 (tbc)

Comment: Could someone change the link from the https://civicrm.org/download page so it points to the right documentation for installing? Currently it points to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/wikis/drupal8-composer which is not very helpful for someone who just wants some easy instructions how to install civi on Drupal 8.

Comment: thx. have passed on

Comment: Thanks for flagging it. Link updated.